# Get Joins query result in iBatis

Tags: java, ibatis

I have parent & child relationship(eg-sales & salesdetails) and while loading sales table, I need to get salesdetails objects as well in iBatis.

The scenario is,

Sales has parent information's and SalesDetails has item wise information's.

I queried, sales and salesdetails using left join to get all the sales with item count.(i have done this)

Now I want to apply this to iBatis to get these query result using those domains...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

See *Advanced Result Maps* in [documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps).